# How to have an event fire when a rectangle is clicked

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to make a game in vb.net and have successfully drawn the game board out of a 2D array of rectangle objects. I want to know if a rectangle has been clicked so I was wondering if anybody knew how to setup the event that would run when a rectangle is clicked.

Comment: what are the "rectangle objects" composed of?  Are they just drawn?

Comment: Yes that are just drawn sorry for not being clearer

Comment: Then they are not objects at all - they are colored pixels. If you know where they are drawn you could capture the click event of something (panel?  picturebox? form?) underneath and see of any of them contain that point.  But at that point, you dont need an event - just do whatever you need to do.

Comment: You might like to check this out to see how to detect clicks on GDI+ drawings: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?588199-Manipulating-GDI-Drawings&highlight=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Capture the click event of the object (panel,form,picture-box) in which you draw your rectangles.
2. Check mouse pointer position and determine if any of your rectangle fall in that position
3. Now perform action on different criteria.

---

For example just create a new project and add the following code.

```
    Dim r As Rectangle
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim p As New Panel
    p.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Me.Controls.Add(p)
    AddHandler p.Paint, AddressOf p_Paint
    AddHandler p.Click, AddressOf P_Click
End Sub

Private Sub p_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim p As Panel = sender
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(p.Handle)
    r = New Rectangle(New Point(10, 10), New Size(100, 100))
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r)

End Sub

Private Sub P_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim p As Panel = sender
    Dim po As Point = p.PointToClient(MousePosition)
    Me.Text = po.X.ToString + "," + po.Y.ToString
    If r.Contains(po) Then
        MsgBox("Yup!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: NOTE: This is for only testing purpose. you can do better than this.

Comment: Yeah this is what I ended up doing not perfect but it works and can be expanded on to make it more robust Thank you.